# Calling String.prototype.split with an array of parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have some logic that requires at some point running of native JavaScript functions and passing "dynamic" arguments to those functions. For example, I need to call the `split` function on an array of arguments defined as `["i want to split this", " " ]`

What i am trying so far is the following:

`String.prototype.split.call("i want to split this", " ")` works fine, but since i have my arguments as an array , then i need to use `apply`. However:

`String.prototype.split.apply(null, ["i want to split this", " " ])`

will not work and i will get `Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.split called on null or undefined`

Something that works is using the `call` with `spread` syntax .. so that:

`String.prototype.split.call(...["i want to split this", " " ])`

but the problem is that my Node.js version does not support `spread` syntax yet.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Why couldn't you reverse your thinking an make your own `split()` function that accepts either a single string or an array and splits accordingly?

Comment: @ScottMarcus the issue here is that i might be calling other native functions like split .. split here is just an example .. but basically it can be any native javascript function

Comment: How are you determining what string gets split? Or on which object a native function may be called. It sounds like you're abstracting too much, IMO.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan to give you a bit of background, these functions are defined as strings inside of a mapping file. They will picked up by a processing function and executed, so basically who writes the mapping has already working knowledge of how arguments should be passed to the function. I hope this answered your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for

```
String.prototype.split.apply("i want to split this", [" "])
```

which is the equivalent to

```
String.prototype.split.call("i want to split this", " ")
```

If you have an array to work with instead of context and arguments separately, you can do

```
var arr = ["i want to split this", " "];
String.prototype.split.apply(arr[0], arr.slice(1))
```

or (if you don't care about mutating):

```
String.prototype.split.apply(arr.shift(), arr)
```

Comment: @Redu That it doesn't work with arbitrarily many arguments. Sure, if `a.length` is guaranteed to be `2`, then that's what you should be using.

Comment: Well, calling [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with more that one string argument doesn't do much, does it?

Comment: Sure, but OP said "*i might be calling other native functions like split*" so I guessed they might be chosen dynamically.